# Moving Bones to Predefined Positions with Tweening

Tags: c#, xna

I am developing a small XNA program in which I would like to make a model of a person move around.

In order to do this, different parts of the person's body should be able to be set to a position in code. For example "move the right arm up" (to a predefined co-ordinate relative to the model).

I have a skinned .X model with bones defined.

What is the best way to achieve this in XNA? Ideally I would be looking for:

1. Some sort of manager/engine where I can run pseudocode like `model.moveBone(Bones.ARM, new Vector3(...));` where the point is relative to the model.
2. Specify a time period during which the bone would be tweened from its current position to the new position
3. Work with inverse kinematics

Comment: I think that your animation should be created outside XNA, and not moving the model bones by code, if I remember well.

Comment: Actually, the model is supposed to move in response to user actions so it would have to be moved in code